# Get URL response after submitting form from Web Pageusing selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am working on automation project and facing problem in one case.

I need to capture response of URL after i submit form from Web Page using selenium.

Here is test case,

1] fill all fields required and submit the form in web page.

2] in developer tools I can see a network URL return OrderNo (unique ID) after submitting form.

3] Now i want to capture this URL using selenium or any other library.

Please help.

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant _HTML_  please.

Comment: since comapny confidential info, i can't share HTML on whihc I am working.